# Getting error while running run_test.pl for an opendds example(Messenger) on linux

Tags: perl, data-distribution-service, opendds

I am trying to run run_test.pl for ***Messenger example given in DCMS for openDDS-3.14 on linux***.But getting error

./run_test.pl

/home/user/OpenDDS-3.14/bin/DCPSInfoRepo -ORBDebugLevel 10 -ORBLogFile DCPSInfoRepo.log -o repo.ior

/home/user/OpenDDS-3.14/bin/DCPSInfoRepo: error while loading shared libraries: libOpenDDS_InfoRepoServ.so.3.14.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222820/discussion-on-question-by-ayush-jain-getting-error-while-running-run-test-pl-for).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run configure and make. Don't set a prefix for configure file on the command line.you will get Messanger example output smoothly using run_test.pl.

Comment: exactly that was what i did. But with no success: error while loading shared libraries: libOpenDDS_FACE